# Traces of products of Gell-Mann matrices in FeynCalc

Tags: linear-algebra, feyncalc

I am working on an assignment in *FeynCalc* and I need to evaluate traces of products of two commutators of Gell-Mann (`SU(3)`) matrices, i.e. I need to calculate the expression

```
SUNSimplify[SUNTrace[Commutator[SUNT[SUNIndex[a]], SUNT[SUNIndex[b]]] 
     Commutator[SUNT[SUNIndex[c]], SUNT[SUNIndex[d]]]], Explicit -> True]
```

but all I get is simply a transcription of the required expression:

> tr(Subscript[T, a].Subscript[T, b].Subscript[T, c].Subscript[T, d])-tr(Subscript[T, b].Subscript[T, a].Subscript[T, c].Subscript[T, d])-tr(Subscript[T, c].Subscript[T, a].Subscript[T, b].Subscript[T, d])+tr(Subscript[T, c].Subscript[T, b].Subscript[T, a].Subscript[T, d])

Also, in a slightly different case, I got the Casimir operators `CA` and `CF` in the result that are not supposed to be there since I do not contract matrices with the same `SU(3)` index. How should I write a GENERAL (applicable also to traces with different `SU(3)` indices) procedure that would force *Mathematica* to rewrite the mention trace into `SUND[a,b,c]`, `SUNF[a,b,c]` and `SUNDelta[a,b]` notation as is shown in [here](http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/SUNTrace/index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the same syntax as in your link:

```
SUNTrace[Commutator[SUNT[SUNIndex[a]], SUNT[SUNIndex[b]]] Commutator[
   SUNT[SUNIndex[c]], SUNT[SUNIndex[d]]], Explicit -> True]
```

EDIT: Addressing additional question from OP's comments

> The thing is that if you write SUNTrace[SUNT[SUNIndex[a]].SUNT[SUNIndex[b]].SUNT[SUNIndex[c]].SUNT[SUNIndex[d]‌​], Explicit -> True] in the FC, you will get the wrong result (even for SUNN->3), instead of the result shown in link at the page no. 38.

It is not a wrong result, because the expression that FeynCalc
returns is equivalent to the one from CORE. Unfortunately, SUNSimplify
is not that good at showing the equivalence of such expressions (it's on my TODO).
In particular it doesn't know about a useful identity for two structure constants
that share one index

$ f^{abe} f^{dce} = \frac{2}{N} (\delta^{ac} \delta^{bd} - \delta^{ad} \delta^{bc}) + d^{ace} d^{dbe} - d^{ade} d^{bce}$

If you supply this identity by hand, e.g. via

```
ClearAll[H];
H[a_, b_, c_] := FCI[SUND[a, b, c] + I SUNF[a, b, c]];
CORE = ((1/8 H[a, b, n] H[n, c, d] + 1/(4 SUNN) SUNDelta[a, b] SUNDelta[c, d]) // Expand //
    ReplaceAll[#, SUNF[a_, b_, r_] SUNF[c_, d_, r_] :>
       2/SUNN (SUNDelta[a, c] SUNDelta[b, d] -
           SUNDelta[a, d] SUNDelta[b, c]) +
        SUND[a, c, r] SUND[d, b, r] -
        SUND[a, d, r] SUND[b, c, r]] &) // FCI
```

Then the rest is trivial

```
(SUNTrace[SUNT[a, b, c, d], Explicit -> True] /. {FCGV["e"] -> n}) -
  CORE // SUNSimplify[#, Explicit -> True] &
```

and you get `0`, showing that both expressions are the same.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Actually, i kinda had a different idea of a solution and today i finally cracked it - it sufficed to interject SUNSimplify and SUNTrace and that did the trick. Also, i wrote a general replacement via `//.` command because it seemed to me that FeynCalc gives a "slightly wrong" result of a trace of a product of four Gell-Mann matrices - atleast for N=3 but i am not really sure about it because i did not look into its conception of a mentioned trace. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: Can you please specify what is "slightly wrong"? The thing is that since last year I'm one of the FC developers (see https://github.com/FeynCalc), so if you found a real bug in SUNTrace or SUNSimplify, we should fix it.

Comment: Of course, I will try to explain what I did not like about the trace of a product of four Gell-Mann matrices, or the `SUNT[SUNIndex[a]]` generators. The thing is that if you write `SUNTrace[SUNT[SUNIndex[a]].SUNT[SUNIndex[b]].SUNT[SUNIndex[c]].SUNT[SUNIndex[d]], Explicit -> True]` in the FC, you will get the wrong result (even for `SUNN->3`), instead of the result shown in [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9507456.pdf) at the page no. 38. I am sorry - I almost got out of characters left. If I did not explain it properly (or specified the problem properly), may I suggest the email contact?

Comment: @tomas00100100 I discussed your example in the edited answer. For FeynCalc related issues you can either contact me directly or use our mailing list. You'll find all the relevant infos here (I'm Vladyslav): https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Support

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I am sorry for replying so late. Your answer was very helpful. Thanks!